# Method consuming POST request with Header and a RequestBody is not called in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have a controller with a POST method like this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pay")
public class PayController {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
    @Autowired
    PayRepository payRepository;
    @Autowired
    PayLogsRepo payLogsRepo;
    @Autowired
    PricingRepository pricingRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/callback",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> callbackUrl(@RequestHeader("merchantId")String merchantId,@RequestHeader("merchantSecret")String merchantSecret,@RequestBody PayRequest payRequest){
        System.out.println("pay ref id "+payRequest.getTransactionDetails().getReferenceId());

        try{

            payRepository.save(payRequest);
            System.out.println("saving pay response");

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse();
        customResponse.setMessage("yo");
        customResponse.setStatus("yun");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

So the callbackurl method is a POST method which is expected to be called with those informations. I also have an interceptor so whenever a call is triggered I get a log from the intercetpor like this
`request url /pay/callback` but the method is never called. This log `System.out.println("pay ref id "+payRequest.getTransactionDetails().getReferenceId());` is never executed. 
The callback url is supposed to be created to accept these sort of parameters show in the image, along with a request body. [image]
But this method is never called. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This method `private ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> callbackUrl` should be `public` or at least default

Comment: @theanilpaudel I ran through your code and it was working fine!!, So I could think of 2 possible reasons your endpoint is: -> 

1) There is some context-path in your spring project which has to be added before /pay/callback

2) Your PayRequest DTO needs to be checked or finally use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` in the consumes


If still that didn't solve the problem, then we need more information on the values returned by this endpoint!!

Comment: when you hit in postman, what is the response and response status code you are getting?

Comment: @Naveen I am getting the correct response on postman

Comment: what do you mean by 'getting correct response'? is it working fine now?